# How to assign Randomly generated values inside of multiple object

Tags: javascript

I want to assign randomly generated numbers in multiple object keys but when I call one key value in another key then I am getting different values but I want to get same value as my previous key how I can do that, help me please.

```js
function randomNum() {
    return {
        random: () => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        },
        sameRandom: () => {
            return randomNum().random();
        },
    };
}
```

I want to get same number in random() and sameRandom().

Comment: @TheBombSquad It's not needless; it's illegible w/o reasonable indentation. Nobody's making you refresh the page.

Comment: May you explain why you need two functions to output a random number? - as for the question itself, you could generate the number outside of the return and have both functions return the same variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--if you explicitly ask for a new random number that's what you'll get. Can you not store the generated random number?

Comment: It logically doesn't make any sense .

Comment: The fact of being random means you will receive different values for each execution. If you want a number with no logic sequence, but that can be replicated, try using some algorithm with prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, same random would activate the function again.. if you want a random value to last, I changed it to this(still not sure why you don't just make `const someOuterVariable=randomNum().random()`)

```js
function randomNum() {
    let randVar=null
    return {
        random: () => {
            return randVar=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        },
        sameRandom: () => {
            return randVar
        }
    };
}

let rand=randomNum()
console.log(rand.random())
console.log(rand.sameRandom())
```

Answer (score 2):

`random` and `sameRandom` methods are immediately invoked.
You can either use closures or some sort of memoization, since each time calling `random` or `sameRandom` would produce a new number it's impossible to track down the order of execution, thus it makes sense to create a refresh method;.

```js
function randomNum() {
  const getRandomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  let latestRandom = getRandomNum(); 
    return {
    refresh: () => latestRandom = getRandomNum(),
        random: () => {
            return latestRandom;
        },
        sameRandom: () => {
            return latestRandom;
        },
    };
}
const s = randomNum();
s.random(); // 62
s.sameRandom(); //62
s.refresh(); // 85
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
randomGenerator = {
  random: () => {
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
    randomGenerator.pastRandoms.push(randomNum)
    return randomNum;
  },
  pastRandoms: []
};

//First time
console.log(randomGenerator.random())
console.log(randomGenerator.pastRandoms)

//Second time
console.log(randomGenerator.random())
console.log(randomGenerator.pastRandoms)
```

When you're trying to access past randoms, it actually just generates a new random number. So, just create a 'history', and push every newly generated number into it, within the `random` function.

Comment: I think this (`console.log(...randomGenerator.pastRandoms);`) would be better as it will be equal to `console.log(randomGenerator.random())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a global variable in `random()` and get it in `sameRandom`. In case `sameRandom` was called and it wasn't set yet, return `random()`:

```js
let rand = null;
function randomNum() {
  return {
    random: function() {
      rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
      return rand; 
    },
    sameRandom: function() {
      return rand ? rand : this.random(); 
    }
  }
}
console.log(randomNum().random());
console.log(randomNum().sameRandom());
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given. you could just have random in your function. and then use a getter to reference it again.

run snippet below

```js
function randomNum() {
    return {
        random: () => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        },
    };
}

const myObj = {
        random:  randomNum().random(),
        get sameRandom(){
        return this.random
        }
      };
      
console.log(myObj);
```